# how to correctly use toUpperCase();

Tags: java

I'm having some problems with some java code so I figured I'd ask it here. I am asked to add a line of code to take care of lower case input, but I'm not sure on how to implement it. I'm probably greatly over looking a very easy fix, but any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Worksheet_7
    {
        public static void main(String[]args)
        {
            Scanner Fred = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Today we practice using switch statements \n\n");
            char Ans;
            System.out.println("What kind of car do you drive");
            System.out.println("(F)ord, (C)hevy, (B)uick,(M)azda,(H)onda");
            String Word = Fred.next();
            Ans=Word.charAt(0);
            switch(Ans)
            {
                case 'C': System.out.println("Chevy-the heartbeat of America");
                System.out.println("Buy a ford");
                break;
                case 'F': System.out.println("Ford tough");
                System.out.println("Nice job cowboy");
                break;
                case 'B': System.out.println("Buick-Luxury you can afford");
                System.out.println("Seriously? A Buick? That's not Luxury");
                break;
                case 'M': System.out.println("Mazda-Zoom, Zoom");
                System.out.println("Can't really say anything");
                break;
                case 'H': System.out.println("Honda-Always dependable");
                System.out.println("Yeah, yeah, yeah");
                break;
                default: System.out.println("Need a better car...?");
            }
             System.out.println("\n\n done for now..");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to change the way you're comparing the `Ans` to the cases, maybe start there

Answer (score 0):

`Fred.next()` is a `String`

You need to call the `String` method of **`public String toUpperCase()`** somewhere.

Note: It returns a new String, and not capitalizes in place.

---

Or there is a `Character` method **`public static Character toUpperCase(char ch)`**

---

Or you can update the cases

```
case 'c':
case 'C':
    ...
    break;
case 'f':
case 'F':
    ...
    break;
```

Comment: it returns a string but he clearly is retrieving the first character of it. Don't get me wrong your suggestion is better than his solution currently.

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw It is less performant to uppercase an entire string, sure

Comment: How much difference could it make?

Comment: @Lew allocating more memory for another string?

Comment: The question was "how much?"

Comment: @Lew depends on the size of the string. Obviously such a simple question, it does not have significant impact

Comment: Exactly. So when people say "less performant" about something that takes nanoseconds out of the whole program, they are focusing on the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, user `String` instead of `char`:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner Fred = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Today we practice using switch statements \n\n");
    String Ans;
    System.out.println("What kind of car do you drive");
    System.out.println("(F)ord, (C)hevy, (B)uick,(M)azda,(H)onda");

    String Word = Fred.next();

    Ans=Word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();

    switch(Ans)
    {
        case "C": System.out.println("Chevy-the heartbeat of America");
            System.out.println("Buy a ford");
            break;
        case "F": System.out.println("Ford tough");
            System.out.println("Nice job cowboy");
            break;
        case "B": System.out.println("Buick-Luxury you can afford");
            System.out.println("Seriously? A Buick? That's not Luxury");
            break;
        case "M": System.out.println("Mazda-Zoom, Zoom");
            System.out.println("Can't really say anything");
            break;
        case "H": System.out.println("Honda-Always dependable");
            System.out.println("Yeah, yeah, yeah");
            break;
        default: System.out.println("Need a better car...?");
    }
    System.out.println("\n\n done for now..");
}
```

Comment: Using `switch(Character.toUpperCase(Ans))` would be better than substring

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the switch to

```
switch (ans.toUpperCase()){
```

Comment: I think you mean `public static char toUpperCase(char ch)`